# An article after 'called'

Tags: articles, mathematics

In my text, many concepts are introduced (defined) by a sentence with 'called'. Examples are:
This condition is called *eigenvariable condition*.
This procedure is called the *truth table method*.
A filter defined like that is called a *trivial ultrafilter*.
Should 'called' be followed by an article? I have a feeling that 'called' makes a difference, and that in 'this formula is the *interpolant* of A and B' the article is fine. Is it so?

Comment: It's somewhat subjective, but I personally agree. If using *called* (and putting the thing in italics or quotation marks), I would tend to omit an article. Otherwise, I'd provide one. You are using words as words, outside of their normal syntax. (***Boys*** **is** *used here* not ***boys*** **are** *used here*.) However, there is no "wrong" way of doing it—it's stylistic rather than about grammar.

Comment: Thank you indeed. I think you managed to verbalize what I and some other people felt or suggested.